# Bash ignoring IFS

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="\n"
cp -R  "$oldpath/*" "$newpath/"
```

I have a script which have to copy folders with spaces and other special characters in their names.

```
+ cp -R '/home/vmail/user@mail.com/Maildir/.INBOX.Drop.The Host/*' '/home/vmail/user@mail.com/Maildir/.DropThe Host/'
cp: cannot stat `/home/vmail/user@mail.com/Maildir/.INBOX.Drop.The Host/*': No such file or directory
```

I run it with bash interpreter.

If I manually copy it from the command line with putting the "/home/vmail/user@mail.com/Maildir/.INBOX.Drop.The Host/" in ""-s it works.

Comment: So what's the question you want answered?

Comment: apparently what is wrong with the syntax and how to fix it

Comment: So please [put that in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/428974/edit), so your question has a question in it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I see the use of setting `IFS` here.

However, the `*` is not being expanded since it's within the double quotes.  You may want

```
cp -R  "$oldpath"/* "$newpath"
```